# Signal or variable counter inside a generate statement

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I have a problem with a generate statement. I'm generating a pipeline architecture, the basic problem is that I need another counter or variable besides the for index:

```
architecture behav of blockPipelineCordic is
    constant total: integer := stepNumber + stepNumber/pipeStep;
    signal signVector: std_logic_vector( (stepNumber - 1) downto 0);
    signal lx: std_logic_vector( ((total + 1)*dataSize - 1) downto 0);
    signal ly: std_logic_vector( ((total + 1)*dataSize - 1) downto 0);
    signal signCounter: integer := stepNumber - 1;
begin

stepGen:
for i in (total - 1) downto 0 generate
    begin

      signCounter <= signCounter - 1 when ((total - i) mod (pipeStep + 1) /= 0) else signCounter;

        stepGen0: if( (total - i) mod (pipeStep + 1) /= 0 ) generate
        begin U1: entity work.cordicStep(behav)
        generic map ((totalStepNumber - 1) - i,dataSize)
        port map(signVector(signCounter),lx(((i+2)*dataSize-1) downto (i+1)*dataSize),ly(((i+2)*dataSize-1) downto (i+1)*dataSize),lx(((i+1)*dataSize-1) downto i*dataSize),ly(((i+1)*dataSize-1) downto i*dataSize));
        end generate stepGen0;

        stepGen1: if( (total - i) mod (pipeStep + 1) = 0 ) generate
        begin U2: entity work.registerModule(behav)
        generic map (dataSize)
        port map(clk,lx(((i+2)*dataSize-1) downto (i+1)*dataSize),lx(((i+1)*dataSize-1) downto i*dataSize));
        end generate stepGen1;

        stepGen2: if( (total - i) mod (pipeStep + 1) = 0 ) generate
        begin U3: entity work.registerModule(behav)
        generic map (dataSize)
        port map(clk,ly(((i+2)*dataSize-1) downto (i+1)*dataSize),ly(((i+1)*dataSize-1) downto i*dataSize));
        end generate stepGen2;

end generate stepGen;
. . .
```

In the generation of the first structure I need to use a different index to signVector, I created a signal to be used as a counter (port map(signVector(signCounter),lx(((i+2)*dataSize-1) downto ) but it cannot be used as an index the error is: "Actual (indexed name) for formal "sub" is not a static signal name."

Any help would be appreciated :), ty

Comment: Your `signCounter` is assigned `total` times ! Remeber that all `<=` are **concurrent** assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't use an intermediate signal like that.

You could write a function, which given a value `i` will return the correct `signCounter`, without needing to store intermediate values.

You could try declaring the signal within the generate, but I don't think it'll get you what you want (the signal will end up with `total` number of drivers on it, rather than having several different values during the loop.)  Generate is for "making static things", not dynamic things.

Comment: Right. In your code, `signCounter` is assigned `total` times ! plus the initialization. @Martin: yes, a signal in the declarative part of the generate is ok.

Comment: @wap26: Yes, I wasn't clear - it's allowed, but whether it provides the function...

Comment: Awesome, I didn't think about using functions, thank you so much, very useful answer. greetings

Answer (score 0):

While I have some issues following your code, it seems that `signCounter` is derivable from `i`.  The math involved would be simpler to follow if you run the generate from 0 to total-1.

Alternatively try splitting it into two generate statements, the first `from 0 to stepNumber - 1` that gerates your `cordicSteps`, and the second `from 0 to total - 1` generating your `registerModules`.

Additionally you can combine `stepGen1` and `stepGen2`

Comment: Sorry for the messy code still getting started in VHDL; and thanks I'll try to derive it from i, I didn't try because It was supposed to be a minor fix to the architecture and didn't wanted to make big changes to the code and I get lost easily with the bus sizes. Greetings